# SwiftUI List Keeps Showing Core Data Items After They Were Deleted

Tags: listview, core-data, swiftui

I'm on my way for exploring SwiftUI and I've encountered an issue. I'got a List of singers saved using Core Data

```
let singer1 = Singer(context: viewContext)
singer1.firstName = "Taylor"
singer1.lastName = "Swift"

let singer2 = Singer(context: viewContext)
singer2.firstName = "Ed"
singer2.lastName = "Sheeran"

let singer3 = Singer(context: viewContext)
singer3.firstName = "Adele"
singer3.lastName = "Adkins"

try? viewContext.save()
```

I've created another view to populate the List with singers.

```
struct ListOfSingers<T: NSManagedObject, Content: View>: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@FetchRequest<T> var singers: FetchedResults<T>

let content: (T) -> Content
init(filterKey: String, filterValue: String, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {
    _singers = FetchRequest<T>(entity: T.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "%K BEGINSWITH %@", filterKey, filterValue))
    self.content = content
    
}

var body: some View {
    
    List {
        ForEach(singers, id: \.self) {
            content($0)
        }.onDelete(perform: deleteSinger)
    }
    
}

func deleteSinger(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    withAnimation {
        
        offsets.map { singers[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
        
        try? viewContext.save()
        
    }
}
```

}

I use a predicate to sort them into 2 lists. The problem I cannot solve is that when I use predicate "S" and delete objects on the List and after that go back to predicate "A" and delete singer on that List I still have the singer shown there, even though I checked the singers' array and it says it's empty. I also can interact with this "ghost" object, but if I try to delete this object app crashes because now it understands that the array is empty and there is such an object to delete.

Here is my ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

@State var lastNameFilter = "A"

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            ListOfSingers(filterKey: "lastName", filterValue: lastNameFilter) { (singer: Singer) in
                Text("\(singer.wrappedName) \(singer.wrappedLastName)")
                    .onAppear { print( "\(singer.wrappedName) \(singer.wrappedLastName)" )}
            }

            Button("Add Singers") {
                let singer1 = Singer(context: viewContext)
                singer1.firstName = "Taylor"
                singer1.lastName = "Swift"

                let singer2 = Singer(context: viewContext)
                singer2.firstName = "Ed"
                singer2.lastName = "Sheeran"

                let singer3 = Singer(context: viewContext)
                singer3.firstName = "Adele"
                singer3.lastName = "Adkins"

                try? viewContext.save()
            }
            .frame(width: 280, height: 50)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding()

            HStack {
                Button("Sort by A") {
                    withAnimation {
                        lastNameFilter = "A"
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 130, height: 50)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)

                Spacer()

                Button("Sort by S") {
                    withAnimation {
                        lastNameFilter = "S"
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 130, height: 50)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Singers") }}}
```

Comment: You only execute your fetch request once so the UI will not be updated. Manually execute it again after a save, or listen to update notifications of your context or adopt the new @FetchRequest property wrapper

Comment: I've adopted a new @FetchRequest property wrapper but there is still the same result. I've tried to manually execute fetch request again, but it failed as SwiftUI doesn't allow to use mutating func because @FetchRequest<T> var singers: FetchedResults<T> is immutable. Have you got other ideas?

Comment: Skip this overly complicated generic ListOfSingers and move the fetch request and the other code into ContentView just to see if it works properly

Comment: I keep my fetch request in another view as I want it to be dynamically filtered, so I can pass different predicates and NSSortDescriptors. If I do fetch request in the ContentView I won't be able to make it dynamic as for example `@State var lastNameFilter = "A"` cannot be used before it's initialized.

Comment: Also, I keep having the same issue even if the generics removed

Comment: I meant for trouble shooting, not as a permanent solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that for some reason ListOfSingers struct was called twice. Even though I've deleted the last singer from Core Data the render time was faster than reindexing of Core Data. So I ended up having a "Ghost View", which was rendered before I item was fully deleted from the Core Data. When I tried to delete a Ghost View I was reaching an array that didn't exist. It always lead to an app crash.

The solution was to add a function that checked if there are any items in Core Data right after deletion fired off.

1. Create `@State var noMoreSingers = false` in the main view to check which view should be presented and add this conditional to the VStack to explicitly tell which view should be presented:

   ```
    VStack {
        if !noMoreSingers {
            ListOfSingers(filterKey: "lastName", filterValue: lastNameFilter) { (singer: Singer) in
                Text("\(singer.wrappedName) \(singer.wrappedLastName)")
            }  } else {
                Spacer()
            }
   ```
2. Add a `@Binding var noMoreSingers: Bool` to `ListOfSingers` to be able to tell the main view when there are no more items in Core Data
3. Add function to Persistanse Controller to get all items:

   ```
        func getAllSingers() -> [Singer] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Singer> = Singer.fetchRequest()

        do {
            return try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error Fetching Users")
        }
    }
   ```
4. Add function to ListOfSingers for fire off `getAllSingers` and check if the retrieved array is empty:

   ```
    func checkIfSingersAreEmpty() {
        let checkSingers = PersistenceController.shared.getAllSingers()
        if checkSingers.isEmpty {
            noMoreSingers = true
        }
    }
   ```

Now everything works!